# React native Hooks sync UseState in 2 diferent files

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I want to sync the value of a useState in 2 different files from a useHook

I have a file named useChangeScreen witch I use to set  when I want to show the diferent Views:

```js
    export const useChangeScreen = () => {
    ...
      const [homeActivo, setHomeActivo] = useState(false);
      const [searchActivo, setSearchActivo] = useState(true);
      const [profileActivo, setProfileActivo] = useState(false);
    ...
      const irAHome = () => {
        setHomeActivo(true);
        setSearchActivo(false);
        setProfileActivo(false);
      };
      const irASearch = () => {
        setHomeActivo(false);
        setSearchActivo(true);
        setProfileActivo(false);
      };
      const irAProfile = () => {
        setHomeActivo(false);
        setSearchActivo(false);
        setProfileActivo(true);
      };
    ...
    return  {
      homeActivo,
      searchActivo,
      profileActivo,
      irAHome,
      irASearch,
      irAProfile
    }
    }
```

This hook is called in the navigation component:

```js
    export const Nav = () => {
      const {
        irAHome,
        irANotifi,
        irAProfile,
        irASearch
      } = useChangeScreen();
    ...
    return (
    ...
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={irAHome}>
    ...
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={irASearch}>
    ...
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={irAProfile}>
    ...
    )
    }
```

and in the screen controller I have this:

```js
export const ScreenController =() => {
  const {
    homeActivo,
    searchActivo,
    profileActivo,
  } = useChangeScreen();
...
return(
...
      {homeActivo ? (
        <HomeScreen />
      ) : searchActivo ? (
        <SearchShopsScreen />
      ) : profileActivo ? null : null}
...
)
}
```

when I press the buttons in the `nav` I want the views in `ScreenController` to change from `Home` to `Profile` or `Search`, but when I press the buttons, the state dont change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **lift up the state** to the parent component and pass it down to it's children, use **React Context API** or **Redux**.

### If you chose to lift up the state:

Then you would have a parent component that looks like this:

```js
// ...
const Parent = () => {
  const {
    irAHome,
    irANotifi,
    irAProfile,
    irASearch,
    homeActivo,
    searchActivo,
    profileActivo
  } = useChangeScreen();

  return (
    <>
      <Nav
        irAHome={irAHome}
        irANotifi={irANotifi}
        irAProfile={irAProfile}
        irASearch={irASearch}
      />

      <ScreenController
        homeActivo={homeActivo}
        searchActivo={searchActivo}
        profileActivo={profileActivo}
      />
    </>
  );
};
// ...
```

Then use the values passed from props like that:

```js
export const ScreenController =({ homeActivo, searchActivo, profileActivo }) => {
  // ...
  return (
      // ...
      {homeActivo ? (
        <HomeScreen />
      ) : searchActivo ? (
        <SearchShopsScreen />
      ) : profileActivo ? null : null}
      // ...
  );
};
```

and:

```js
export const Nav = ({
  irAHome,
  irANotifi,
  irAProfile,
  irASearch
}) => {
  // ...
  return (
    // ...
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={irAHome} />
    // ...
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={irASearch} />
    // ...
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={irAProfile} />
    // ...
  )
}
```

#### Note:

You should've actually used only one state which stores the current screen and checked for the current screen using comparison operators.

Checkout these for more details:

1. [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)
2. [React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)
3. [Get Started with Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)

Comment: Thanks, Im using the React Context to fix it :)